# JPA Populate Data on App Start

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working on developing a mechanism to load data into the database on boot for JPA. We are using the code first approach with JPA/Hibernate, so hibernate is actually generating the schema every time the applications starts. The kicker is I only want this to happen when the active profile is "dev" however I think I'm on the right track there. I have seen suggestions of using a bean to do this but I think I'm not quite getting it.

This is the code I has so far.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DataInitializer {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public DataInitializer dataInitializer() {

        User user = userRepository.findByUserName("admin");
        if (user == null) {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.setUserName("admin");
            newUser.setEmail("admin@app.com");
            newUser.setFirstName("Application");
            newUser.setLastName("Admin");
            newUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("password"));
            userRepository.save(newUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach but I was able to get it working with the following code.

```
@Component
@Profile("dev")
public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Test");
        user.setLastName("User");
        user.setEmail("email@google.com");
        user.setUserName("admin");
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("PASSWORD"));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```